# Does resetting CMOS via rear IO do the same thing as shorting the clear CMOS pins?

Tags: bios, motherboard, reset

Some mainboards like the MSI MEG X570 UNIFY have a clear CMOS button on the rear IO. However, when it comes to resetting the CMOS, support or "veteran" forum members always recommend removing the battery with the PSU unplugged, or shorting the clear CMOS pins.

The question is: do all these methods do the same thing? Does restoring to factory defaults in the BIOS/UEFI menu do the same thing?